# ActionScript LineStyle Color Changing Prematurely

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, line, draw

i'm attempting to draw lines beside each other, but the last line from the first color group takes on the color from the second color group before the second color is assigned.  can anyone explain this?

```
function drawCorner()
    {
    var corner:Sprite = new Sprite();
    corner.graphics.beginFill(0x0, 1.0);
    corner.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

    corner.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x00FF00, 1.0);    
    corner.graphics.moveTo(1, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 1);
    corner.graphics.moveTo(6, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 6);
    corner.graphics.moveTo(11, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 11);

    corner.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0xFF00FF, 1.0);    
    corner.graphics.moveTo(0, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 0);
    corner.graphics.moveTo(5, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 5);
    corner.graphics.moveTo(10, 13);
    corner.graphics.lineTo(13, 10);

    corner.graphics.endFill();

    addChild(corner);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. Try putting each block in its own function and then see what happens when you call em.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code into a test component and it draws as expected: three green diagonal lines with a single red line offset by one pixel from the first line.  Maybe post some of the surrounding code for more clues?

Comment: i've updated my code for with the full function.  if you zoom in after it's drawn, you'll notice that the shortest lines at the bottom right are the same color.  at least they are for me.  i'm using the latest 10.1 flash player.

Comment: I just encounted the same issue with a simple attempt to draw two parallel lines in different colours, on the PlayBook.  It's actually unrelated to the endFill(), or at least it can occur even without that, since mine has nothing but the two sets of lineStyle()/moveTo()/lineTo() commands.  Putting the second lineStyle() after the moveTo() of the second set works around the problem.  So did you file an Adobe bug report?  I'm sure it's a bug.

Comment: i forgot all about this problem.  long time!  no, i didn't end up filing a bug, peter.  please comment back if you find the time to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not entirely sure **why** this is happening, it **is** happening because of your placement of `corner.graphics.endFill();`

Place the endFill call immediately after the drawRect and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the

```
corner.graphics.moveTo(0, 13);
```

before you change lineStyle.

Comment: you're right.  the whole thing seems a bit counter-intuitive, though.  even having to end the fill prior to making the line color changes is a bit ridiculous.  i suppose i can see there's no real benefit to ending the fill last in the function, and doing so can make the code more  difficult to read, but i still feel like filing a bug to adobe about this.